# locationManager deprecated in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, xcode, core-location, swift3, ios10

I have downloaded the last version of XCode to test my project in iOs 10 Beta. When I have opened it, XCode asked me if I wanted to convert my project to Swift 3. After doing that, one error appeared :

> Cannot override 'locationManager' which has been marked unavailable:
>   APIs deprecated as of iOS 7 and earlier are unavailable in Swift

And my code is the following :

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateToLocation newLocation: CLLocation, fromLocation oldLocation: CLLocation) {
    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

    currentUserLocation = newLocation
}
```

Is there another "not deprecated" function to achieve the same result ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This method replaced the one you're using:

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, 
                     didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

}
```

Find out more [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/CLLocationManagerDelegate/locationManager:didUpdateLocations:).